# Here maps removing all the polyline, markers instead of just just the marker

Tags: html, angular, typescript, here-api, heremaps

The problem is like this.
When the user clicks on a traceroute link in our app it opens a popup with here maps, showing the polyline with multiple markers in it. And on the same popup there is another table that has a map icon, when clicked shows only one marker in the here maps. The problem is both the multiple markers and single marker are showing properly initially(first time) but when i press the map icon that just shows only one marker for the second marker to be shown the removeObjects get called and it removes all the polyline and the markers that was previously shown(good) but then it stops showing the new marker and the previously passed polyline in the map(hence the problem to come here). can anybody help me solve this challenge.

```
 addMarkerToGroup(group, coordinate, html) {
    this.marker1 = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);
     
    // var marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);
    // add custom data to the marker
    this.marker1.setData(html);
    group.addObject(this.marker1);
  }
  addInfoBubble(map,data1,ui) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++ ) {
    var group = new H.map.Group();
  
    map.addObject(group);
  
    // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
    group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
      // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
      // for all objects that it contains
      var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
        // read custom data
        content: evt.target.getData()
      });
      // show info bubble
      ui.addBubble(bubble);
    }, false);
    
    this.addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat: data1[i].start_latitude, lng: data1[i].start_longitude},
      '' +data1[i].stop_address+
      '');
    }

  }
  addInfoBubble1(map,data1,ui) {
    // for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++ ) {
      
    var group = new H.map.Group();
  
    map.addObject(group);
  
    // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
    group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
      // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
      // for all objects that it contains
      var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
        // read custom data
        content: evt.target.getData()
      });
      // show info bubble
      ui.addBubble(bubble);
    }, true);
    
    this.addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat: data1.start_latitude, lng: data1.start_longitude},
      '' +data1.stop_address+
      '');
    // }

  }

addMarkertopolyline(map,data) {
  // console.log(data[0].length, "polylineaddmarker", data);
  let objm = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < objm.length; i++) {
    // for (const va in objm){
    // for (let k = 0; k < data[i].length; k++ ){
    this.group = new H.map.Group();
    map.addObject(this.group);
    // console.log(data[0][k], "polyline2address",data[0][k].length);
    if (i == 0) {
      var coords = { lat: objm[0].latitude, lng: objm[0].longitude },
      
      
        marker0 = new H.map.Marker(coords, {icon: new H.map.Icon('../../../../assets/images/truckstartb1.svg', {size: {w: 36, h: 36}})});
      map.addObject(marker0);
      map.setCenter(coords1);
      this.group.addObject(marker0);
    }
    if (i == objm.length - 1) {
      var coords1 = { lat: objm[objm.length - 1].latitude, lng: objm[objm.length - 1].longitude },
  
      
        marker0 = new H.map.Marker(coords1, {icon: new H.map.Icon('../../../../assets/images/flagsb2.svg', {size: {w: 36, h: 36}})});
      map.addObject(marker0);
      map.setCenter(coords1);
      this.group.addObject(marker0);
    }

    // map.addObject(marker0);
    // map.setCenter(coords1);
    // this.group.addObject(marker0);
    // this.group.addObject(marker1);
  }
}

addMarker(map,data1) { 
 
  for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { 
  
       
    this.iconHMap = new H.map.Icon("../../../../../assets/images/cargogrey.svg", {size: {w: 36, h: 36}});
     var icon = this.iconHMap;
   
    this.group = new H.map.Group();
    map.addObject(this.group);
    // console.log(this.iconHMap,"icon");
    var coords = { lat: data1[i].start_latitude, lng: data1[i].start_longitude },
      icon1 = {icon: this.iconHMap},
      // coords = {lat: lat, lng: lng},
      marker = new H.map.Marker( coords, {icon: this.iconHMap});
    map.addObject(marker);
    map.setCenter(coords);
    this.group.addObject(marker);
  }
}
addMarker1(map,data1) { 
    
  // for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { 
  
   
    this.iconHMap = new H.map.Icon("../../../../../assets/images/cargogrey.svg", {size: {w: 36, h: 36}});
     var icon = this.iconHMap;
  
    this.group = new H.map.Group();
    map.addObject(this.group);
    // console.log(this.iconHMap,"icon");
    var coords = { lat: data1.start_latitude, lng: data1.start_longitude },
      icon1 = {icon: this.iconHMap},
      // coords = {lat: lat, lng: lng},
    marker = new H.map.Marker(coords, { icon: this.iconHMap });
  
  var coords = { lat: data1.start_latitude, lng: data1.start_longitude },
    icon1 = { icon: this.iconHMap };
   var marker = new H.map.Marker(coords, { icon: this.iconHMap });
    map.addObject(marker);
    map.setCenter(coords);
    this.group.addObject(marker);
  // }
}

  addPolylineToMap(map, data) {
    
      console.log("traceroutekkkk", data[0].latitude);
      var lineString = new H.geo.LineString([data[0].latitude, data[0].longitude, 0]);
      // var growingPolygon = new H.geo.Polygon(lineString),
      //   growingShape = new H.map.Polygon(growingPolygon);

      let objl = data;
      let ob;
      let obj;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < objl.length; i++) {
        this.polyline = { style: { lineWidth: 4 } };
        // console.log(objl[i].latitude, "lat and long1", objl[i].longitude);
  
        lineString.pushLatLngAlt(objl[i].latitude, objl[i].longitude, 0);
    
  
        map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(lineString, this.polyline));
        
        
      }
  
 
    }
  
  loadMap1(data, data1) {
   
    const platform = new H.service.Platform({
      apikey: 'q3j2RP34Zz5SdH2bFYIVQP1PbMGSSh4PH3OjLml0oaA'
    });
    const layers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
    this.div = document.getElementById('hereMap'); // this.mapDiv.nativeElement
    const map = new H.Map(this.div, layers.vector.normal.map, { pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio, center: { lat: this.lat1, lng: this.long1 }, zoom: 5, });
    this.hereMap = map;
    // add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());
    //Step 3: make the map interactive
    // MapEvents enables the event system
    // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.hereMap));

    // Create the default UI components
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.hereMap, layers);
  

    // Window resize handler
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
      map.getViewPort().resize();
    });
    this.addPolylineToMap(this.hereMap, data);

    
      this.addMarker(this.hereMap, data1);

    this.addMarkertopolyline(this.hereMap, data);
   
      this.addInfoBubble(this.hereMap, data1, ui);
  
    console.log(this.hereMap, "heremaps2.2");
  }
  removeObjects() {
    if (this.traceroutelist1.length > 1) {
      this.hereMap1.removeObjects(this.group.getObjects());
      // this.group.removeObjects();
    }  
  //   if(this.traceroutelist1.length > 1){
  //     let objects = this.group.getObjects().filter((item) => {
  //       console.log(item, "heremapobjects0");
  //     return item.type === H.map.Object.Type.MARKER;
  //  });
  //     console.log(objects, "heremapsObjects");
  //   }
  }
 
  loadMap(data, data1) { 
    
    
  const platForm1 = new H.service.Platform({
    apikey: 'q3j2RP34Zz5SdH2bFYIVQP1PbMGSSh4PH3OjLml0oaA'
  });
  const layers1 = platForm1.createDefaultLayers();
  this.div1 = document.getElementById('hereMap1');
    const map = new H.Map(this.div1,layers1.vector.normal.map,{ pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,center: {lat: this.lat1, lng: this.long1},zoom: 5,});
this.hereMap1 = map;
  // if (this.traceroutelist1.length > 1) { 

  //   this.hereMap1.removeObjects(this.hereMap1.getObjects());
  //   const layers1 = platForm1.createDefaultLayers();
  // this.div1 = document.getElementById('hereMap1');
  //   const map = new H.Map(this.div1,layers1.vector.normal.map,{ pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,center: {lat: this.lat1, lng: this.long1},zoom: 5,});
  //   this.hereMap1 = map;
  // } 
    
  
 
  // add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => this.hereMap1.getViewPort().resize());
  //Step 3: make the map interactive
  // MapEvents enables the event system
  // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
  var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.hereMap1));

  // Create the default UI components
  this.ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.hereMap1, layers1);
  

  // Window resize handler
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
      map.getViewPort().resize(); 
  });
  this.addPolylineToMap(this.hereMap1, data);
  this.addMarker1(this.hereMap1, data1);
  this.addMarkertopolyline(this.hereMap1, data);
  this.addInfoBubble1(this.hereMap1, data1, this.ui);
    console.log(this.hereMap1, "heremaps1.0");
}
```

And here is the html part

```
<div [class.show]="isHereMap" [class.hide]="kmtrack" [class.none]="transfer">
          <div  #map id="hereMap"></div>
     
    </div>
    <div [class.show]="isHereMap" [class.hide]="kmtrack" [class.showpointer]="transfer">
      <div  #map id="hereMap1"></div>
 
</div>
```

And this is the function that calls the traceroute when the map icon is clicked

```
 mapReady1(row) {
    
    this.transfer = true;
    this.isHereMap1 = true;
    this.isHereMap = false;
    this.kmtrack1 = true;
    const d = new Date();
    console.log('time', d);
    const fdate = this.datepipe.transform(d, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log(this.fdate, 'this.date===>>>');
    const ftime = '12:00 am';
    const ttime = this.datepipe.transform(d, 'hh:mm a');
    console.log('ttime', ttime);
    this.startdatetime = fdate + ' ' + ftime;
    this.enddatetime = fdate + ' ' + ttime;
    const dt = new Date(this.enddatetime);
    const d1 = dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1); // 24 hour format old code
    var t = new Date();
    t.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // 12 hour format new code
    this.traceStart = this.datepipe.transform(t, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a');
    console.log(this.enddatetime, 'this.traceStart---', this.traceStart);

   
    const req1 = {
      role: this.data.userdetails.rolename,
      userId: this.data.userdetails.usersid,
      user_id: this.data.userdetails.usersid,
      company_id: this.data.rowdata.company_id,
      start_date: this.traceStart + '/' + this.enddatetime,
      vehicle_id: this.data.rowdata.vehicle_id,
    };
    console.log('data2c1>>>>>>>', req1);
    
    this.tracerouteService.getTracerouteList(req1).subscribe((response) => {
      this.responsedata = response;
    //  console.log('trace11 response===>>>', this.responsedata);
      this.kmtrack = false;
      this.transfer = true;
      this.isHereMap1 = true;
      this.isHereMap = false;
      if (this.responsedata.success === "true") {
        this.icondest1 = this.icondest;
        this.iconstart1 = this.iconstart;
        
        this.kmtrack = false;
        this.visible = true;
        this.value = this.responsedata.data.totalValue;
        this.trackVehicleResponse = this.responsedata.data.totalValue;
        console.log(row,'vc11--', this.trackVehicleResponse);
        
        this.traceroutelist = this.responsedata.data.trace;
        console.log('traceroute===ll===>>>>', this.traceroutelist);
        this.traceroutelist1.push(this.traceroutelist);
        console.log(this.traceroutelist1.length, "traceroute4maplist", this.traceroutelist1);
        this.removeObjects();
        this.loadMap(this.traceroutelist, row);
        this.addPolylineToMap(this.hereMap1, this.traceroutelist);
        this.addMarker1(this.hereMap1, row);
        this.addMarkertopolyline(this.hereMap1, this.traceroutelist);
        this.addInfoBubble1(this.hereMap1, row, this.ui);
        
        this.obj = this.traceroutelist;
        this.tlen = this.obj.length;
        // console.table(this.obj);
        this.lat2_1 = this.latSelected;
        this.long2_1 = this.longSelected;
        this.traceroutelist.forEach((latAndLong: any) => {
          this.lat = parseFloat(latAndLong.start_latitude);
          this.long = parseFloat(latAndLong.start_longitude);

          // console.log(latAndLong, 'click01>>>', );
          return (this.latAndLong02 = Array(latAndLong));

          // return this.long01, this.long02;
        });
      
      } else {
        this.lat1 = 23.473324;
        this.long1 = 77.947998;
        this.zoom = 4;
        this.boundcheck = false;
        this.visible = false;
      }

      return this.latAndLong02;
      // this is the end of the logic for polyline
    });
    // this.zoom0 = 6;
    // console.log('zoom011', this.zoom0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function addInfoBubble: the place of definition of object Group is wrong.

In most cases the line like `var group = new H.map.Group();` should be run only once and create some global (or global for some scope) variable `group` but your code `var group = new H.map.Group();` is running in the loop `for` that is wrong.

When you will define the `var group = new H.map.Group();` only once then you need define this `group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {` once as well.

Your function `addInfoBubble` then will be look better so :

```
addInfoBubble(map,data1,ui) {
    var group = new H.map.Group();//<-- maybe this group should be belongs to global scope?
    map.addObject(group);
    // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
    group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
      // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
      // for all objects that it contains
      var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
        // read custom data
        content: evt.target.getData()
      });
      // show info bubble
      ui.addBubble(bubble);
    }, false);

    for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++ ) {
    
       this.addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat: data1[i].start_latitude, lng: data1[i].start_longitude},
      '' +data1[i].stop_address+
      '');
    }

  }
```

In function `addInfoBubble1` you defined one group and push to it only one marker. This is strange because the Group is using to union more than one map object.

In function `addMarkertopolyline` is the some issues with group like function `addInfoBubble`: `this.group = new H.map.Group();`

In function `addMarker` is the some issues with group; If you have many markers on the map then Create Icon object only once as global variable and reuse it for all (if applicable) markers.

In function `addPolylineToMap`: the line `map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(lineString, this.polyline));` should be after loop `for` like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < objl.length; i++) {
        this.polyline = { style: { lineWidth: 4 } };
        // console.log(objl[i].latitude, "lat and long1", objl[i].longitude);
  
        lineString.pushLatLngAlt(objl[i].latitude, objl[i].longitude, 0);
       
        
      }
map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(lineString, this.polyline));
```

In functions `loadMap` and `loadMap1` you have double defined `window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());` - should be once.

Please double check that functions `loadMap` and `loadMap1` are invoked **only one time**.

Please keep in mind that **all above snippets of code I didn't test** it couldn't work if  you do simple copy & paste, therefore please then don't say "This code, which you provided, doesn't work!". But I am very sure that the idea of above code is correct.